# why vfork() causes the parent process crash(segment fault)?

Tags: c, fork, vfork

The vfork can change variables in parent process, but why can't it increase the stack?

```
void f1()
{
    vfork();
}
```

f2() leads to the crash.

```
void f2()
{
    char buf[100];
}


int main()
{
    f1();
    f2();
    _exit(0);                                                                                                                                    
}
```

If I change vfork() to fork(), the crash won't happen.

Comment: Don't bother learning `vfork()`. Simply use `fork()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you're allowed to do after calling `vfork()` is execute a file. It's right in [the documentation:](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfork)

> The `vfork()` function shall be equivalent to `fork()`, except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type **pid_t** used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec` family of functions.
>
> ...
>   >
>   The use of `vfork()` for any purpose except as a prelude to an immediate call to a function from the `exec` family, or to `_exit()`, is not advised.

To wit, **the only legal calls are `_exit` and [`exec*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).**